# How to extract all the strings between 2 patterns using regex Notepad++?

Tags: regex

Extract all the string between 2 patterns:

Input:

```
test.output0    testx.output1    output3    testds.output2(\t)
```

Output:

```
output0    output1    ouput3   output2
```

Note: ("  ") is the tab character.

Comment: This will help `\.\w+(?=\t|$)`. See demo https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
\.\w+$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`\.`** - Matches `.` literally. If you do not want `.` to be included in your pattern; please use `(?<=\.)` or simply remove `.`.
- **`\w+`** - Matches word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` 1 or more time.
- **`$`** - Represents end of the line.

You can find the demo of the regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/1)

#### Result Snap:

[image: Pictorial Representation]

### EDIT 2 by OP:

According to your latest edit; this might be helpful.

```
.*?\.?(\w+)(?=\t)
```

**Explanation:**

- **`.*?`** - Match everything other than new line **lazily**.
- **`\.?`** - Matches `.` literally zero or one time.
- **`(\w+)`** - Represents a capturing group matching the word-characters one or more times.
- **`(?=\t)`** - Represents a positive look-ahead matching `tab`.
- **`$1`**  - For the replacement part `$1` represents the captured group and a **white-space** to separate the output as desired by you. **Or if you want to restore `tab` then use the replacement `$1\t`.**

Please find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/5)

#### Result Snap 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mandy for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: Mandy, I have this mentioned string is occurring multiple times within the same line. I want to extract all the strings withing this line.

Comment: @ShankarMG I'm glad I could help =)

Comment: it really does :)

Comment: Yes, I did. BTW I have made some changes can u pls take a look. I just got new issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mandy. Will take care of that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try matching on the following pattern:

```
Find: (?<![^.\s])\w+(?!\S)
```

Here is an explanation of the above pattern:

```
(?<![^.\s])  assert that what precedes is either dot, whitespace, or the start of the input
\w+          match a word
(?!\S)       assert that what follows is either whitespace of the end of the input
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: @ShankarMG Please consider the updated working answer.

Comment: Tim, I just got a new issue. I have updated the same. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @ShankarMG You should really avoid changing your question like this, after you have already accepted an answer.  I updated my answer in any case.

Comment: I will make a note of that Tim. Thanks a lot :)